# How to write a Custom Alert inside a Non activity class in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view, android-inflate

I have to write a custom alert on a nonactivity class to show that from all activities.
I have used inflater for the custom alert but it crashes the app. Please see the below code.Please suggest a solution for this

```
  AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

      //  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlayout, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        TextView btn_ok = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        TextView txt_dia = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txt_dia);

        txt_dia.setText(msg);

        if(subAlertDialog != null && subAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
            return;
        }
        subAlertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        subAlertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
        subAlertDialog.show();
        btn_ok.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            subAlertDialog.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code it will help you.

```
 //Call dialog from activity 
   CustomDialog.showDialog(this);

//This is your custom dialog class
public class CustomDialog {

public static void showDialog(Context context){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlayout, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    TextView btn_ok = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    TextView txt_dia = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txt_dia);

    txt_dia.setText("abc");
    btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.create().show();
}
}
```